# Black,white Color of datatable row hide the row data

Tags: css, primefaces, colors, datatable, styles

Am using Primefaces Datatable on this way:
each object of datatable has attribute color saved in database depends on this color it will be the color of its row.
in the case of row black color without selecting this row,data are not readable as font is black.
in case of row white color and i selected the row,data also are not readable because in case of selection font changed to white color.

1-Any advice on how to solve this issue by putting in consideration the first case will apply on all dark colors and second case will apply for all light colors?

2-Also any solution for coloring the whole row depending on the color attribute in one statement without getting this color in each column (style="background-color: #{lottiBean.getColor(lotto)}">)

```
<p:dataTable id="lottiTable" widgetVar="lottiTable" var="lotto"
                resizableColumns="true" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{lottiBean.selectedLotto}" rowKey="#{lotto.idLotti}"
                value="#{lottiBean.allLottis}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,25,50" rows="10" 
                style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px" 
                sortBy="#{lotto.dataLotto.time}" sortOrder="DESCENDING" 
                paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {Exporters}">
<f:facet name="{Exporters}">
    <p:commandLink id="excel" ajax="false">
        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="excel.png" width="24" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="lottiTable" fileName="Lotti" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false" immediate="true">
        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" width="24" />
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="lottiTable" fileName="Lotti" />
    </p:commandLink>
</f:facet>
<p:column headerText="#{messages.label_unita_operativa}" filterBy="" style="background-color: #{lottiBean.getColor(lotto)}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{lottiBean.getUoCode(lotto)}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="#{messages.label_codiceLotti}" filterBy="#{lotto.codiceLotti}"
    sortBy="#{lotto.codiceLotti}" style="background-color: #{lottiBean.getColor(lotto)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{lotto.codiceLotti}" />
</p:column>
```

AND HERE IS MY GETTING COLOR METHOD:

```
public String getColor(Lotti lotti) {
    String colorValue=null;
    try {
        if (lotti != null) {
            if (lotti.getCrLottiuos() != null && lotti.getCrLottiuos().iterator().hasNext())
                colorValue = lotti.getCrLottiuos().iterator().next().getIdUo().getIdColore().getCodiceColore();//GET COLOR FROM DATABASE AS HEXA VALUE EX:#FFFFF0
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        colorValue = null;
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return colorValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your needs are not really clear, but here is a solution to how to add a column in `p:databale`, to display a color saved on the database, this may help you :

```
<p:column headerText="coulor" >
      <div style="display: compact;" >
          <span class="ui-button-text">
               <span 
                    style="overflow:hidden;
                    width:1em;height:1em;display:block;
                    border:solid 1px #000;text-indent:1em;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    background-color:##{lotti.color}">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</p:column>
```

When it comes to coloring a row of a datatable, you can use `rowStyleClass` to restyle a row :

```
rowStyleClass="#{ lotti.color == 'ff3d3d' ? 'redClass' : lotti.color == '3D46FF' ? 'bleuClass' : null }
```

Visit primefaces showcase for more information about how to condition row styling: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml

Comment: Hi thnks for your help,
My needs simply that when  the row is black colored or any dark color as the font is black by default no data can be read,so i need an advice for how to make data readable if the row is dark colored